# How to get the shaded region of the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

I have this problem:

[image]

So my development was:

Denote side of rectangle with: $2a, 2b$.

So, $4ab= 64, ab = 16$

Denote shaded region with $S$

Denote area of triangle $DGH = A_1$ and triangle $FBE = A_2$.

So, $A_1 + A_2 + S = 64$

$S = 64 - A_1 - A_2$

The triangles $A_1, A_2$ are congruent because $LAL$ congruence criterion.

The area of $A_1$ and $A_2$, is the same and i got it with this way:

Since, the $\angle{GDH} = 90$ and the median from this angle to the base $HG$, that is the altitude of the triangle $DGH$,  will measure the half of the $HG$ side.

And the $HG$ side by Pythagorean theorem, will be $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, that will be the base of the triangle.

And the altitude will be: $\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2} $,

So the Area of $A_1 = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{4}$

So, $A_1 + A_2 = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}$

Then, $64 - (\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}) = S$

And, $-(a^2 - 8ab + b^2) = 2S$

And I have not been able to continue from here, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\triangle DGH$ is similar to $\triangle DCA$. Since the ratio of their sides is $1:2$, the ratio of the areas is $1:4$, so area of $\triangle DGH$ is 1/8 of the whole rectangle.

Comment: Note that there is an error in your development: The median to the base HG is not the altitude of the triangle DGH, except when the triangle is isosceles. In general, the altitude is $ab/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, hence S is $ab/2$.

Comment: My error was assume that is a isosceles triangle and all its secundary elements coincide

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The area of hatched region of the rectangle  is the area of the rectangle minus the sum of the areas of the right triangles $BEF$ and $DGH$. Now if you glue these triangles along their hypotenuses, you obtain a rectangle  with dimensions half the dimensions of the big rectangle, hence with area equal to ¼ area of the big rectangle.

Hence the required area is ¾ big area, i.e. $\color{red}{48}$.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks

Answer (score 34):

Hint:

[image]

- there are eight small red triangles all with the same area
- six of them are shaded

Comment: How you know that?

Comment: @Mattiu Each has perpendicular sides half the lengths of the sides of the original rectangle

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you notice that if you combine two right triangles then they occupy the area of $\dfrac14$ of the total area.

So, the area of the shaded region is $=64-\dfrac14(64)=64-16=48$

Comment: What do you mean with $G = E $ ?

Comment: Length of the midpoint from the vertices

Comment: Well, what is the lenght of the rigth triangle ? is the Hypotenuse?

Comment: The length of the right triangle is nothing but the length of the midpoints

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Because the triangles connecting the midpoints with the vertices are all congruent, we have:

$$\color{grey}{A}=64-2A_{DHG}$$
$$\color{grey}{A}=2A_{DHG}+A_{GHEF}$$

Addinng the two relations:

$$2\color{gray}{A}=64+A_{GHEF}$$

But, $A_{GHEF}=\frac{A_{ABCD}}{2}$ (I'll let you figure out why yourself as an (easy) exercise), and therefore:

$$\color{gray}{A}=\frac{96}{2}=48$$

Answer (score 2):

By [Midpoint theorem](http://users.humboldt.edu/flashman/mdptthrm.html), area of triangle DHG is $\frac{1}{4}$ of triangle ACD. So, $$ar(DHG)=0.25*ar(ACD)=64/(2*4)=8$$

By symmetry, ar(unshaded region)=$8*2=16$
So, ar(Shaded region)=$64-16=48$

Answer (score 0):

If your sidelengths are $2a$ and $2b$, how do you think you could represent $|\triangle GHD|$ and $|\triangle EFB|$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? (Keeping in mind that $E,G,H,F$ are midpoints.)